# Trying to evaluate NDSolve inside of FindRoot

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, physics

I want to find the equation for the range of a projectile as a function of its elevation angle at launch.

Currently, I am stuck in my effort to calculate the time. What I have doesn't work right although it's what I was recommended to do.

```
tfinal[theta_] =
 FindRoot[
   y[t] /.
     NDSolve[
       {m y''[t] == -m g + 0.4 x'[t],
        y[0] == 0,
        y'[0] == vi Sin[theta], 
        m x''[t] == -0.01 x'[t] Abs[Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2]],
        x[0] == 0,
        x'[0] == vi Cos[theta]},
       {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 100}],
   {t, 0, 20}]
```

Any help you could give me to make this work, and how to plug it into `x[t]` later would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the values for `vi` and `m` and `g` because I don't think `NDSolve` will work without those.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue) and [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent). First give your constants numerical values:

```
m = 10; g = 9.8; vi = 1000;
```

Then, use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue) + [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent):

```
Clear[tfinal];
pf = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {
    m y''[t] == -m g + .4 x'[t], y[0]==0, y'[0]==vi Sin[θ],
    m x''[t] == -.01 x'[t] Abs[Sqrt[x'[t]^2+y'[t]^2]], x[0]==0, x'[0]==vi Cos[θ],
    WhenEvent[y[t]==0, tfinal=t; "StopIntegration"]
    },
    {tfinal, x[tfinal], x[t], y[t]},
    {t,0,1000},
    θ,
    Method->{"ParametricCaching"->None}
];
```

The [`Method`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Method) option is used to prevent caching, as caching also disables the [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent)when the same angle is repeated. For example:

```
pf[45 Degree][[;;2]]
```

> {151.405, 877.313}

Visualization:

```
ParametricPlot[
    pf[45 Degree][[3;;]],
    {t, 0, pf[45 Degree][[1]]},
    AspectRatio->1,
    PlotRange->All
]
```

[image]